# Delete icon in Custom UITableViewCell Shown Beneath the Row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I implemented the code to let my table to be edited:

```
   -(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.editing)
    {

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }

}
```

but the icon "Delete" is shown underneath the cell (which is a custom cell).

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        ClientCellFooter* cell = (ClientCellFooter*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ClientCellFooter"];
        [cell setTableView:tableView];
        [cell setController:self];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        if ([self.allClients count] == 1)
             [cell.imageBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]];
        else
            [cell.imageBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"]];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
}
```

Could somebody help me to understand how to put the icon over the row?

Comment: Put your cellForRowAtIndexPath method's code :)

Comment: You add the icon on cell or cell's contentView?

Comment: The icon is that from iOS when you go in edit mode...

Comment: @Ranju : added the code, but I don't think it will help

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Put this in the custom cell implementation:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        for (UIView *subview2 in subview.subviews) {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview2 class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) { // move delete confirmation view

                [subview bringSubviewToFront:subview2];

            }
        }
    }
}
```